# Is there a JavaScript regex equivalent to the intersection (&&) operator in Java regexes?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

In Java regexes, you can use the intersection operator `&&` in character classes to define them succinctly, e.g.

```
[a-z&&[def]]    // d, e, or f
[a-z&&[^bc]]    // a through z, except for b and c
```

Is there an equivalent in JavaScript?

Comment: Not seeing much point to the first example, as it's equivalent to `[def]`. Am I missing something? The second one makes sense (and is cool).

Comment: It wouldn't be much use anyway because JavaScript has limited shorthand character classes, and no Unicode support. I guess it *might* be useful for Unicode ranges, but it doesn't save much typing. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @Kobi: What do you mean "no Unicode support"? JavaScript uses Unicode natively (UTF-16, specifically) and supports Unicode escape sequences in regular expressions, including within character classes.

Comment: @TJ - I meant JavaScript's regular expressions, not JavaScript as a whole. It can't make `'אבג'.match(/\w+/)` match (i.e. no `/u` flag), and doesn't have `\p{L}` shorthand character classes. You can define them yourself, of course, but that isn't fun.

Comment: @T.J.: I know what you mean about the first example - I guess they didn't want to distract us with usefulness?

Comment: @Kobi: I was talking about regular expressions. It's true that the definition of `\w` is English-centric (which is odd, the definition of `\s` isn't, it includes all Unicode "space separator" characters, though implementations sometimes get that wrong). But because `\w` is defined in a simplistic way (and one I really hope they fix in v6), that doesn't mean there's "no Unicode support."

Comment: @Kobi: Actually, I shouldn't even call the `\w` definition English-centric, as it breaks on lots of English words (mostly ones we've adopted from other languages, but long enough ago to be really English now), like "naïve".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent in JavaScript?

Simple answer: no, there's not. It is specific Java syntax.

See: [Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694) by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan. Here's [a sneak-peek to the relevant section](http://books.google.com/books?id=yY_EsWFMj-QC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=java%20%22character%20class%22%20intersection&source=bl&ots=dDHdsT41UF&sig=2Y9zXezzVXNOS-i2NGIiv1K-TGc&hl=en&ei=EUgUTvDcFIOBOq6VoKYL&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=java%20%22character%20class%22%20intersection&f=false).

Probably needless to say, but the following JavaScript code:

```
if(s.match(/^[a-z]$/) && s.match(/[^bc]/)) { ... }
```

would do the same as the Java code:

```
if(s.matches("[a-z&&[^bc]]")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, there isn't an equivalent, but you can achieve the effect of `&&` using a look-ahead. The transformation is:

```
[classA&&classB]
```

becomes:

```
(?=classA)classB
```

For instance, this in Java:

```
[a-z&&[^bc]]
```

has the same behavior as this:

```
(?=[a-z])[^bc]
```

which is fully supported in JavaScript. I don't know the relative performance of the two forms (in engines like Java and Ruby that support both).

Since the `&&` operator is commutative, you can always use either side for the (positive or negative) look-ahead part.

Intersection of a class with a negated class can also be implemented with negative look-ahead. So the example above could also have been transformed to:

```
(?![bc])[a-z]
```

Answer (score 2):

### 2023 answer: Yes, there is.

With [the `v` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicodeSets):

```
[[a-z]&&[def]]
[[a-z]&&[^bc]]
```

Try them [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xdSyvR/1).

You can also do subtraction: `[[a-z]--[bc]]`. More information can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Character_class#v-mode_character_class).

Comment: It even works in my Opera. :D Still I'd hesitate to use this in production, better waiting some more years.

Comment: @bobblebubble Just like with any other new features in JS `:)` Babel does have [good support for `v`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-unicode-sets-regex), however.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same result as the Java regexes in JavaScript by writing out the character classes longhand, e.g.

```
Java           JavaScript   English
------------   ----------   -------
[a-z&&[def]]   [def]        d, e, or f
[a-z&&[^bc]]   [ad-z]       a through z, except for b and c
```

It’s just a bit more verbose/obscure in some circumstances, e.g.

```
Java               JavaScript
----------------   -----------
[A-Z&&[^QVX]]      [A-PR-UWYZ]
[A-Z&&[^CIKMOV]]   [ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]
```